# Will 8 bit addition in 8085 gives 16 bit result?

Tags: microprocessor

If two 8 bit numbers are added in 8085 microprocessor, will it give 16 bit result, if so where it will be stored, because Accumulator can store only 8 bit.

Comment: Typically addition will result in 8bit, but set a carry or overflow flag. Don't know specifically about 8085

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the 8085 indeed only has an 8-bit accumulator.

In case there is an overflow during the addition, this will be indicated using the carry bit within the status register.

You can either test this bit, or perhaps make use of the ADC instruction, which not only adds another thing to the accumulator, but it also takes the carry input from the status register. That way you could perhaps get some 16-bit result.

Or maybe you could use one of the DAD instructions, and set the higher registers to zero, and using the lower registers as inputs for your thing.

Either way, read the manual. :)